# How to shim virtual method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

How to cope with situation, when type got virtual method and I need to provide a Shim instead?

I have data contract, with code:

```
public class ServiceResponse
{
    ...
    public virtual string Serialize() {...}
    ...
}
```

In my code there is call to `response.Serialize()`, where `response` is type of `ServiceResponse`.

In my unit test I would like to do something like this:

```
ShimServiceResponse.Serialize = () => { return "serialized response"; };
```

But while the `Serialize` method is `virtual`, type `ShimServiceResponse` does not provide `Serialize` method to be "Shimmed".

What is the best way to solve this situation? Thanks.

I am using Microsoft Fakes Framework, .NET 4.5.2 and VS 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work it out by creating child `class` and overriding `Serialize` method.

```
class ServiceResponseChild : ServiceResponse
{
    public override string Serialize()
    {
        return "orgUnitsResponse serialized";
    }
}
```

Later in my tests I am using this child `class`.

```
...
ServiceResponse response = new ServiceResponseChild();
target.SaveResponseAsXml(response);
...
```

Although this is works for me, would be interested in other solutions utilizing the MS Fakes capabilities (if possible).